# Constructing a finite automata from a subset of its language

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata, regular-language

I am attempting to solve the following problem:

Let $M=(Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F)$ be a deterministic finite automata which accepts $L(M)$, and let $E$ be the subset of $L(M)$ consisting of all words of even length. Show how to construct a deterministic finite automata, $M'$ accepting $E$.

I feel I nearly have a solution, but I am not quite there. This is my approach:

In order to construct $M'$ we may duplicate the states of $M$, so that we may have $q_{Meven}$ and $q_{Modd}$. Rather than going from $q_1$ to $q_2$, we would go from $q_{1odd}$ to $q_{2even}$. Only accept states in $F_M$ and $Q_{even}$ would be accepted.

So, $M'=(Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F)$, where:

$Q=Q_{even}\cup Q_{odd}$, where $Q_{even}=Q_{odd}=Q_M$

$q_0=q_{0even}$, and

$F=F_{M}\cap Q_{even}$.

$\delta = $

- if $(q_n\in Q_{odd})\space q_{n\space odd}\rightarrow q_{n+1\space even} $
- if $(q_n\in Q_{even})\space q_{n\space even}\rightarrow q_{n+1\space odd} $

Is this the correct approach? Are my terms (such as $Q_{even}$) sufficiently defined? If not how would I define them? Does my transition function make any sense?

Automata theory is fairly new to me, so while I might have the right idea in my head, it is difficult to translate that to the formal language used in automata theory. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is fine. You could tidy up the definitions a bit to make it a bit clearer, but I had no trouble figuring out what you were doing.

Using primes for the parts of the new automaton, you might, for instance, let $Q'=Q\times\{0,1\}$, $Q_0'=Q\times\{0\}$, and $Q_1'=Q\times\{1\}$; my $Q_0'$ is your $Q_{even}$, and my $Q_1'$ is your $Q_{odd}$. I’ll let $F'=(F\times\{0\})\cap Q_0'$ and $q_0'=\langle q_0,0\rangle$. Finally, I’ll define

$$\delta':Q'\times\Sigma\to Q':\big\langle\langle q,i\rangle,\sigma\big\rangle\mapsto\big\langle\delta(\langle q,\sigma\rangle),1-i\big\rangle\;.$$

Then $M'=\langle Q',\Sigma,\delta',q_0',F'\rangle$ does what you want (and is really just a more formal, carefully presented version of your machine).

(By the way, *automata* is plural: the singular is *automaton*.)

Answer (score 1):

Before computing an automaton, you may first try to obtain a formal description of the language you are looking for. Here, the language $E$ is the intersection of $L(M)$ and of the set of words of even length. Formally
$$
  E = L(M) \cap (\Sigma^2)^*
$$
Now, it is easy to find a DFA accepting $(\Sigma^2)^*$ and hence, the problem reduces to find an automaton accepting the intersection of two regular languages, given a DFA recognizing each of them. You certainly have learnt this algorithm.

Doing so, you will observe that you arrive exactly at the solution proposed by Brian M. Scott.